# How to calculate the correlation based on a condition (specific timeframe)

Tags: r, conditional-statements, correlation

I am trying to calculate the correlations between two values for a certain timeframe, which is based on a specific data. The data is written in a different data frame than the values that are the base for the calculation of the correlation.
I am stuck in drawing the condition from the other database

Here is some trial data:

```
Year1 <- c(2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004) 
COMP1 <- c(1, 1, 2, 6, 9, 5, 2, 1, 3, 2, 9, 6, 6, 1, 8, 5) 
COMP2 <- c(2, 3, 3, 3, 6, 4, 1, 0, 1, 3, 6, 1, 6, 1, 8, 8)  
COMP3 <- c(2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 1, 0, 4, 2, 2, 1, 6, 1, 1)  
COMP4 <- c(25, 29, 16, 17, 6, 20, 8, 21, 12, 17, 31, 32, 21, 1, 2, 1)

DF1 <- data.frame(Year1, COMP1, COMP2, COMP3, COMP4)

Year2 <- c(2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004) 
COMP6 <- c(3, 2, 4, 12, 18, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 18, 12, 7, 2, 16, 10) 
COMP7 <- c(4, 6, 6, 6, 12, 8, 2, 0, 2, 6, 12, 2, 7, 2, 16, 16)  
COMP8 <- c(9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 0, 0, 2, 0, 8, 4, 4, 2, 7, 2, 2)  
COMP9 <- c(50, 58, 32, 34, 8, 40, 9, 42, 24, 34, 62, 64, 42, 2, 4, 2)


DF2 <- data.frame(Year2, COMP6, COMP7, COMP8, COMP9)


Date <- c(2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2003, 2003, 2004, 2004)
DF_CONDITION <- data.frame(Date)
```

What I am trying to achieve is:

- Search the year in the DF_CONDITION and add two years (building the specific time series)
- Then, calculate the correlation between the values in DF1 and DF2 for the respective time series, meaning that ONLY the values from the conditioned timeseries shall be considered.

So far, I was able to calculate a "normal correlation", but I don't know how to start with the condition. Can somebody help me?

Comment: It seems like you might be looking for a thing called "time lagged cross correlation".  Read more about this topic and see if it is what you need.

Comment: Hi David, thanks four your answer. It seems like the "time lagged cross correlation" is not really what I am looking for. The condition (so the year that is indicated) shall only act as a starting point to determine the timeframe for the correlation. I do not want to calculate any effects from that condition, but only the starting point. From what I read, the time lagged cross correlation investigates if one time series predicts the other. But this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Hi @Li4991, I am sorry that I misunderstood your situation.  Perhaps we may work an example? I do not quite understand the correlations that you require.  Let us take Year = 2001 from `DF_CONDITION`.  Is the next step that you wish to calculate the correlations between `DF1` and `DF2`, where Year = 2001? Do you want something like `cor(DF1$COMP1[DF1$Year1>=2001], DF2$COMP6[DF2$Year2>=2001])`? It may be useful for you to write explicitly the numbers or columns that you wish to correlate. It is also not clear what the time series is, unless you mean 2001, 2001, 2001...